# Python hierarchical dictionary from flask to HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am creating a frontend on HTML where I am trying to achieve contextual filters. HTML page is on the below link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zKAu1Ws6iJs6hRNsnnfq8i1m4LWCWa2R/view?usp=sharing

The HTML code has sample data hardcoded, but I want to pass that from a flask application. Here is my flask code. My html page works fine when using hardcoded data, but when I am passing data from flask by creating a similar dict it is not populating state, city and landmark dropdowns. Not sure if the error is in flask or html side. Please help

```py
import pyodbc
from flask import json

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER= {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; SERVER=;DATABASE=;UID=;PWD=')  

from  flask import Flask, render_template, request, json, jsonify
app = Flask (__name__)  
@app.route("/")
def index():
    data = {}
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute ("select  distinct  country,state,  city,  landmark from [dbo].[BI_Master]")
    hierarchical_data = {}
    for row in cursor.fetchall():

        country, state, city, landmark = row.country, row.state, row.city, row.landmark

    # If country does not exist in the dictionary, add it
        if country not in hierarchical_data:
            hierarchical_data[country] = {
            'states': [],
            'cities': {},
            'landmarks': {}
        }

# If state does not exist in the country, add it
    if state not in hierarchical_data[country]['states']:
        hierarchical_data[country]['states'].append(state)
        hierarchical_data[country]['cities'][state] = []
        #hierarchical_data[country]['landmarks'][state] = {}

# If city does not exist in the state, add it
    if city not in hierarchical_data[country]['cities'][state]:
        hierarchical_data[country]['cities'][state].append(city)
        hierarchical_data[country]['landmarks'][city] = []

# Add landmark to the city
    hierarchical_data[country]['landmarks'][city].append(landmark)

    
    # print(row)
    print(json.dumps(hierarchical_data))
    return render_template('index22.html', hierarchical_data=json.dumps(hierarchical_data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Help me with the creating a frontend similar to the html page attached, further I want to use that filter selection to again execute a SQL query and retrieve the output in Excel format.